# Want to get set value in javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html

I want my code to display 170, 122 . All the values have been set in Javascript but still I am not getting the output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <button onclick="UidToPost()">Get It</button>
      <script>
         var SetUid1 = "170";
         var SetUid2 = "122";
         var SetUid3 = "135";
         var SetUid4 = "144";

         var c = 0;
         var timingToSend;
         var SetUid;

         function UidToPost() {
            c = c + 1;
            var postTo = "SetUid" + c + "";
            document.getElementById("do").innerHTML = postTo;
            timingToSend = setTimeout('UidToPost()', 1000);
         };
      </script>
      <p id="do"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

**This is the code that I am using**

```
 var SetUid = [ "170", "122", "135", "144" ];

 var c = 0;
 var timingToSend;

 function UidToPost() {
    var postTo = SetUid[c++];
    document.getElementById("do").innerHTML = postTo;
    if (c < SetUid.length)          
       timingToSend = setTimeout(UidToPost, 1000);
 };
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Like we ask so many - **what** isn't working?

Comment: **I want to my code display 170, 122 and as follow**

Comment: He didnt ask what you wanted, he asked what wasn't working (Do you get an error, does nothing happen...?)

Comment: There is no need to put everything in bold. Please refrain from doing that unless actually used to emphasise something.

Comment: your code shoud display the strings "SetUid1","SetUid2" ... so the variable names and not the vaules? does it? you should use arrays.

Comment: Result is : SetUid1 , SetUid2 as follow..

Comment: there's plenty of good answers, you you want a dirty trick you can use eval("SetUid"+c+"") as in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rMdFg/ but it is bad practice, much better with arrays

Answer (score 3):

Use an array instead of discreet variables;

```
     var SetUid = [ "170", "122", "135", "144" ];

     var c = 0;
     var timingToSend;

     function UidToPost() {
        var postTo = SetUid[c++];
        document.getElementById("do").innerHTML = postTo;
        if (c < SetUid.length)          
           timingToSend = setTimeout(UidToPost, 1000);
     };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("do").innerHTML = window[postTo];
```

You should also get in the habit of avoiding the string argument version of setTimeout as it can cause security issues:

```
timingToSend = setTimeout(UidToPost, 1000);
```

I presume you'll also want to call clearTimeout() (or avoid setting the last one in the first place), e.g., after your variables are finished.

Finally, this might have been done more easily and flexibly with an array, but the above is how you can do it with your current approach.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to dynamically create the name of the variable to use with string concatenation, which is possible but not with that syntax. Since your variables are global variables, they'll be stored in the `window` object, so you can access them like this:

```
window["SetUid1"]
window["setUid2"]
//etc
```

With that in mind, you'll simply need to change this line:

```
var postTo = "SetUid" + c + "";
```

to:

```
var postTo = window["SetUid" + c];
```

You'll also need to handle the case where that variable *doesn't* exist (i.e. they click the button again after the last variable has been displayed), and take appropriate action (probably cycle back to the beginning).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/nC69f/) is a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
document.getElementById("do").innerHTML = window[postTo];
```

You still have to perform a check for the number of vars. Now after the 4th var is displayed, the function will now write "undefined" to the screen because you keep looping.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working, is that you're concatenating the string `SetUid` with the current count `c` to make a string, and adding that to the `innerHTML` of the div.

Instead, you should hold your values in an array and use your variable `c` as an index to that array:

```
     var values = [170,122,135,144]
     var c = -1;
     var timingToSend;
     var SetUid;

     function UidToPost() {
        c = (c + 1) % values.length; 
        var postTo = "SetUid" + c + "";
        document.getElementById("do").innerHTML = values[c];
        timingToSend = setTimeout('UidToPost()', 1000);
     }
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/RsKZj/